# Curl 60 error when enabling SSL on Laradock multiproject setup

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, curl, laradock

I set Laradock as multiproject and enabled SSL on the sites using nginx. The websites load successfully with HTTPS, but the PHP curl calls fail with:

> cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

I have already tried this:

downloaded `cacert-2022-02-01.pem` and appended the local [CA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) pem file to it as well

**php-fpm/Dockerfile**
COPY cacert-2022-02-01.pem /certs/cacert.pem

**php-fpm/php7.3.ini**
curl.cainfo = /certs/cacert.pem

I also tried adding the local CA .crt file to ca-certificates in both nginx and php-fpm and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Try appending the actual self-signed certificate itself to the cacert.pem file and see if it works. Was the self-signed cert actually generated from a fake CA, or is it a standalone cert?

Comment: I generate the cert locally. Tried that as well no result. im starting to think im starting to think. perhaps it uses an alternative path or overrides it at some point